# mouseOut not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple hover event that shows a larger image when the thumbnail is hovered. I'm running into a problem because it works fine in everything except Safari. Can anyone help me? :) Thanks so much!!

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3jpGD/embedded/result/

Here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
#content{
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
}
#thumb{
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}
#largeImage{
    height: 341px;
    width: 512px;
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
    background-size: contain;
    display: none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="largeImage"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="thumb">
        <img src="image.jpg" height="150" width="250" />
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var thumbImage = document.getElementById("thumb");
var hoverImage = document.getElementById("largeImage");

thumbImage.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
    if(!event) var event = window.event;
    var pos = getPos(event);
    hoverImage.style.top        = pos.Top + 30 + "px";
    hoverImage.style.left       = parseInt(pos.Left /2, 10) + "px";
    hoverImage.style.position   = "absolute";
    hoverImage.style.display    = "block";
});

thumbImage.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    hoverImage.removeAttribute("style");
});

function getPos(e){
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    return {Top:e.clientY, Left:e.clientX};
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm running the latest safari dev preview Version 6.1 (8537.54.1) and it seems to be working there.  Maybe the answer is "wait for it…" :)

Comment: I see the same thing in Safari as I do in Chrome. What version are you using and what should happen that isn't happening?

Comment: Maybe change 'mouseleave' with 'mouseout'? What should be the expected result?

Comment: I'm running Safari Version 6.0.5 (8536.30.1) on Mac OSX Mountain Lion

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu That fixed it. I'm not sure why though since I tried both of them before. (I even changed the jsFiddle on my local machine before I pasted the code here. And I have both versions. Maybe it's magic I'll look into it.

Comment: Read more here http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/

Comment: maybe also Safari is not accepting the Eventlistener function without Parameter. Try to add `alert("Hello World");` to see, if the handler is even triggered or not.

Comment: @dognose Yeah it's triggering the alert. I'm just trying to remove the styling added in the mousemove function. Maybe the mousemove is being fired even outside of the div with the thumb?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but is there any reason you don't want to use JQuery?

Comment: @SeanKendle I should for something like this just so I don't have to waste time on Cross Browser stuff. But I like keeping page size down as much as possible since this is going to be implemented on an old ASP page that's WAY to slow already. I'm going to look at the jQuery source just to see how their cross browser solution is written.

Comment: Your code works for me with mouseout. Mac OS X 10.6.8, Safari 5.1.9 http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/3jpGD/3/

Comment: @kol yeah I'm getting the same result. But it only works on their page. Not on my local machine, or MAMP. Does anyone know if jsFiddle does something unique on their servers? Which could fix this problem?

Comment: Isn't "mouseleave" an IE-only event?

Check out this article:  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

Comment: Also:  http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html

Answer (score 1):

it is an bug

see more: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4117

check the site to know more about it

Comment: 2023 bug is still present 10 years later. Safari the new IE.