# mouseleave does not fire on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, mouseleave

I've this function perfectly working on chrome and firefox (both on macOs). I've checked it in safari 10.03(macOs) and it fire on mouseenter but not on mouseleave.

Function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$("#mazzo").on("mouseenter", ".pick", function() {
    var immagine = $(this).data('immagine');
    $("#anteprima").attr("src", immagine);
});
$("#mazzo").on("mouseleave", ".pick", function() {
    $("#anteprima").removeAttr("src");
console.log("Mouse out");
}); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="peranteprima">
<img id="anteprima" src="immagini/void.png" alt="">
</img>
</div>

<div id="mazzo">
<div class="pick" id="0" data-immagine="immagini/12345.png">
<img src="immagini/pick.png" alt="immagine box" class="box">First pick
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#peranteprima {
position: relative;
margin-left: -213px;
}

#anteprima {
position: fixed;
bottom: 75%;
top: 0%;
max-width: 215px;
height: 322px;
z-index: 10;
}
```

I've tried to set .attr("src", "") but the behaviour on safari it's the same. I've also tried mouseout but with no luck.

The mouseleave event reference say this:

> Safari 7 fires the event in many situations where it's not allowed to,
>   making the whole event useless. See bug 470258 for the description of
>   the bug (it existed in old Chrome versions as well). Safari 8 has
>   correct behavior

I've checked many times for a solution here and on other sites but I've found only unanswered question or nothing that fit my problem right now.
There's a way to make it work on safari?

Comment: did you try mouseout instead?

Comment: Yes, but nothing changes

Comment: Look at MDN. I think your safari version is out of date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave

Comment: I've checked it in safari 10.03(macOs)

Comment: See this post. It is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239909/mouseout-not-working-in-safari

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MouseOver MouseOut issue in Safari/Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809971/mouseover-mouseout-issue-in-safari-chrome)

Comment: It's similar to my problem but it's not the same, I think there's something wrong with my code

Comment: you have incomplete html in example.

Comment: Updated, the div with id="0" (and the rest) it's generated after the page it's loaded with a click function

Comment: I've created jsfiddle and tested with browserstack in safari7 - all ok: https://jsfiddle.net/hnkwnrok/1/

Comment: Checked, but still wont work for me (your jsfiddle on safari 10)

Comment: So If it works on safari 7 it can be bug on safari 10.

Comment: I don't think this works correctly http://jsfiddle.net/qLCY3/4/

Comment: You jsfiddle works with safari7